# Maven release plugin not using configured username

Tags: maven, svn, ssh, maven-release-plugin, public-key

I am using maven-release-plugin:2.5.1.  I need to configure it to connect to SVN using public/private key authentication.  I'm having problems getting the configuration to use the correct username when attempting the SSH connection to SVN.

My deploy-settings.xml `<server>` config looks like:

```
<server>
  <id>my.server.org</id>
  <username>[XXXX]</username>
  <privateKey>/home/[YYYY]/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
</server>
```

My pom.xml `<scm>` config looks like:

```
scm:svn:svn+ssh://my.server.org/data1/svns_zzzz/zzzz/path/to/the/project/trunk
```

My `mvn` command line looks like:

```
--batch-mode  release:clean release:prepare release:perform  
-s /home/[YYYY]/.m2/deploy-settings.xml 
-Dsettings.security=/home/[YYYY]/.m2/master-settings.xml
```

When I tried the above configuration it failed.  It could not commit the modified POM file to SVN.  To help debug this problem, I set the following environment variable:

```
SVN_SSH="ssh -vvv"
```

When I did this, I saw in the debug statements too many authentication failures with a username other than the `[XXXX]` username defined in the `<server>` tag.

So then I tried to specify the username in the command line:

```
--batch-mode -Dusername=[XXXX] release:clean release:prepare release:perform...
```

That didn't work.

So then I tried to specify the username in the POM:

```
scm:svn:svn+ssh://[XXXX]@my.server.org/data1/svns_zzzz/zzzz/path/to/the/project/trunk
```

That didn't work either.

To debug and verify my `[XXXX]` username and `/home/[YYYY]/.ssh/id_rsa` key did in fact work, I added them to the environment variable:

```
SVN_SSH="ssh -vvv -l [XXXX] -i /home/[YYYY]/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

After setting the environment variable like this, it worked.  The release plugin was able to successfully commit the modified POM file to SVN.  So I know the username and password work.

So now the question is what is wrong with my Maven configuration?  Setting the SVN_SSH environment variable helped diagnose the problem, and provides a work-around but I don't want to leave it as a long-term solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/faq.html#credentials) says that you need to add the property `project.scm.id` that contains the `id` of your `<server>` configuration. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The release plugin forks the build, and doesn't pass the arguments you provide on the command line to the forked process by default.  Try adding this: `-Darguments="-s /home/[YYYY]/.m2/deploy-settings.xml -Dsettings.security=/home/[YYYY]/.m2/master-settings.xml"` (note double quotes) to the current command line.  This should pass the changes to the forked processes.

Comment: I did need to use "-Darguements=xxxxx" in order to pass those values to the forked processes.  However, if I added -Dusername=[XXXX] to this arguments list the SCM processes still did not use this username when attempting SSH communication with Subversion.

Comment: If the username for the server is in the settings.xml server element, it should not be necessary to specify it on the command line.  Add the `project.scm.id` property mentioned by @StefanFerstl so the release plugin finds the correct server element: `<properties><project.scm.id>my.server.org</project.scm.id></properties>`.

Comment: Both were tried and unfortunately still didn't work.

Comment: Are you still seeing the same information in the debug logs with the new configuration or are they different now?  Also, what version of Maven are you using?

Comment: Using version 3.0.4.  logs are basically the same.  What eventually happens is that I get a log (from having set ssh -vvv) which says the the Unix user that's running Bamboo had too many authentication failures.  So it seems like Maven is never using the username and private key file I'm tyring to configure.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that you were trying to do this with Bamboo.  Does it work if you use plain command line Maven?  Perhaps the issue is with the Bamboo/Maven interface (and I know nothing about Bamboo).